# How to make a notch filter in R

Tags: r, filter

I'm trying to remove the noise from eeg data. I found the band pass filter.
But I couldn't find the notch filter in R.

This is my code band pass filter.

```
fil_N <- 128 
fs <- 500 #sampling rate
fn <- fs/2
fc <- c(0,60) #cut the frequency from 0Hz to 60Hz
fc_norm <- fc/fn
fir_filter <- fir1(fil_N, fc_norm, type="pass")
```

Is there way how to remove the noise using R like a notch filter ?
Thank you for your helping!

Answer (score 0):

The notch filter is basically the opposite of the "pass". In this case, the "stop" filter.

I suppose you would like to use a notch filter for the mains frequency (60hz or 50hz depending on which country you are in).

re-using your code:

```
fil_N <- 128 
fs <- 500 #sampling rate
fn <- fs/2
fc <- c(49,61) # remove frequencies from 49Hz to 61Hz
fc_norm <- fc/fn
fir_filter <- fir1(fil_N, fc_norm, type="stop")
```